# Ruby on Rails website worked locally, routes correct, but on heroku get 404

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, routes

This is a really strange error that I've encountered. I use ruby on rails. Everything works fine locally (on cloud 9) and I successfully pushed it to Heroku. I have run db:migrate with no error. Nonetheless, I get error "The page you were looking for doesn't exist" and the log says 404. I have checked the files and they have been correctly uploaded. 
My routes:

```
  root 'application#index'
  get '/index/:type' => 'application#index'
  get '/index/' => 'application#index'
  get '/benchmark/' => 'application#benchmark'
  get '/benchmark/:type' => 'application#benchmark'
  get '/benchmarkupdate/:name' => 'application#benchmark'
  get '/indexupdate/:name' => 'application#index'
```

I have files in correct locations. I don't see any problem with routing and it has worked locally.

Heroku Logs:

```
2017-04-18T03:13:14.455398+00:00 app[web.1]: * Version 3.8.2 (ruby 2.3.4-p301), codename: Sassy Salamander
2017-04-18T03:13:14.455399+00:00 app[web.1]: * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
2017-04-18T03:13:14.455399+00:00 app[web.1]: * Environment: production
2017-04-18T03:13:15.493228+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: `config.serve_static_files` is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 5.1.
2017-04-18T03:13:15.493241+00:00 app[web.1]: Please use `config.public_file_server.enabled = true` instead.
2017-04-18T03:13:15.493243+00:00 app[web.1]:  (called from block in <top (required)> at /app/config/environments/production.rb:25)
2017-04-18T03:13:16.337785+00:00 app[web.1]: * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:49146
2017-04-18T03:13:16.337997+00:00 app[web.1]: Use Ctrl-C to stop
2017-04-18T03:13:16.847301+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2017-04-18T03:13:18.094441+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=protected-coast-54392.herokuapp.com request_id=3d8c7a3f-3f40-4747-862f-7e70e7c9029e fwd="152.3.34.25" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=75ms status=404 bytes=1744 protocol=https
```

Is there anything else that might cause this problem?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please add the relevant code and logs to the question itself as text. Not screenshots. On the toolbar is a `{}` button that formats the text as code.

Comment: @Xlsaax I don't see a stack trace or anything all that useful in your Heroku Logs. Is there a stack trace like there was with the WEBrick error?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you haven't set a root route meaning when someone goes to www.example.com without any path after it they are going to the root route. In your routes file add something like

```
root 'application#index'
```

or whatever controller and action and the corresponding view that you want people to go to when they first visit your site.

Comment: In my routes file, I have already had root 'application#index', but the website is still not working; I have also tried /benchmark, /indexupdate (which are in my routes) with no avail. I think there's definitely something wrong with routes but I can't really find any and it's working locally

Comment: Based on your log, the lack of a root route was the cause of your 404 error. But there may be other issues. Try loading the Puma gem. Webrick is not meant to be used in production.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for one thing you should not be running WEBrick on production. I'm not positive if this is causing your error, but I'd start there.

Heroku currently recommends `puma`.

You can install puma by including it in your `Gemfile` as `gem 'puma'` and then running bundle install.

In your project directory you will need to include a `Procfile` that tells your app how to run its web server.

> Make sure the `Procfile` is properly capitalized and checked into git.

It should look something like this:

```
# <Rails.root>/Procfile
web: bundle exec puma -t 5:5 -p ${PORT:-3000} -e ${RACK_ENV:-development}
```

Here's an article about [WEBrick](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-default-web-server) and one on [how to set up puma](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server).

You'll need to re-push to heroku. See if that helps. Cheers.

Comment: It looks like @SteveCarey is right to me, based on the error you're getting, but I'm going to leave my answer as you should definitely swap out WEBrick on production! :-)

Comment: Hi, I have swapped to Puma but I still encounter the same error. Is it possible that my routes file (which is correct) is somehow not used or loaded by the server, so the server doesn't know the routes, which causes the error? How is that possible though?

Comment: Yes: `2017-04-18T01:22:28.050384+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=protected-coast-54392.herokuapp.com request_id=9bdcf557-2ed8-4a46-b013-b16866fa4c5b fwd="152.3.34.25" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=99ms status=404 bytes=1744 protocol=https`